# What should I modify to prevent deadlock on c++ thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, deadlock

Here is my source code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "thread"
#include "mutex"

int count0=0 ,count1 =0;
std::mutex main_thread;
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(main_thread, std::defer_lock);

void Function00(long millisecond){

    while (true){

        lck.lock();
        count1++;
        printf("count0:%d count1:%d \n",count0,count1);
        lck.unlock();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(millisecond));

    }
}

void Function01(){

    std::thread th(Function00, 1000);//count per 1 s

    do{
        lck.lock();
        count0++;
        lck.unlock();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));//count per 0.5 s
    } while (1);

}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Function01();


    return 0;
}
```

I then use the command to build my .o file:

> g++ -std=c++11 -pthread testa.cpp -o a.o

However, it shows the error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Resource deadlock avoided
Aborted
```

I feel confuse and no idea to solve it, so i try in Microsoft VS2013, and it runs with no error... I feel confuse to it. Is it the problem in linux? What should i modify to prevent the deadlock?

Comment: You're locking `lck` twice. You definitely shouldn't be doing this

Comment: do you mean i need to create another thread?

Comment: what if i use a function to create thread everytime it run, will it come to deadlock?

Comment: I think you don't need this locking at all, just modify values and print them. Or must these values be modified in some particular way?

Comment: get rid of uniquelock and just use plain mutex with your current logic..it will work

Comment: i am sorry, what is rid? how to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unique_lock` cannot be locked twice, if you want to lock a mutex on two threads so that one of them will block, you need to use two `unique_lock`s.

```
void Function00(long millisecond){

    while (true){

        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(main_thread);
            count1++;
            printf("count0:%d count1:%d \n",count0,count1);
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(millisecond));

    }
}

void Function01(){

    std::thread th(Function00, 1000);//count per 1 s

    do{
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(main_thread);
            count0++;
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));//count per 0.5 s
    } while (1);

}
```

Comment: I am sorry that i am the beginner of it, so i need to create two thread?

Comment: @Question-erXDD: no, you just need a `unique_lock` per thread.

Comment: what if there are multiple functions(eg >4) work concurrently, can one thread do this for all?

Comment: @Dani isn't `std::lock_guard` enough for this?

Comment: @Question-erXDD: How would you have 4 functions concurrently with one thread?

Comment: wt are the different between std::lock_guard & std::unique_lock ?

Comment: @Question-erXDD: `lock_guard` Can only be locked by the constructor and unlocked in destruction, `unique_lock` can be locked and unlocked at any time.

Comment: @Dani: I mean each function has its own count like one count score, one count time, one is display thread and one one is create_thread_for_another_counter

Comment: @Question-erXDD: I don't understand the problem

Comment: Ops sorry for my poor presentation. give an example, if we have a server, it will keep listen if there is an client. assume client A comes, server will create a new thread to keep the connection with client A while the original thread(maybe main thread) will keep on listen. so if we only have a unique (which only handle 2 thread?), how to handle the new thread created?

Comment: @Question-erXDD: allocate the unique_lock on the stack, each thread will have one of its own.